# FInd location of element in a vector

Tags: algorithm, apl, array-algorithms, dyalog

I'm new to APL and I would like to find the position of an element(s) within a vector. For example, if I create a vector of 50 random numbers:

```
lst ←  50 ? 100
```

How can I find the positions of 91 assuming it occurs 3 times in the vector?

Thanks.

Comment: `50?100` chooses randomly 50 _distinct_ ints from `⍳100` (that is 0...99 or 1...100 depending on `⎕IO`). 91 will never occur more than once. You probably want `?50⍴100`.

Comment: Thanks ngn, I should have realised that ? generates unique values only

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an expert, but a simple way is to just select the elements from `⍳ 100` where the corresponding element in `lst` is `91`

```
(lst=91)/⍳100
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to write `≢lst` rather than `⍳100` just in case `lst` length changes?

Answer (score 4):

With Dyalog 16.0, you can use the new monadic function `⍸` "Where".

```
⍸lst=91
```

`lst=91` gives a vector of 0s and 1s. Applying `⍸` on this gives the locations of all the 1s. This also works if `lst` is a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **ngn, Cows_quack and Probie**. I should have read Mastering Dyalog APL more carefully as it also mentions this on page 126. So taking all the answers together:

```
⍝ Generate a list of 100 non-unique random numbers
lst ← ?100⍴100

⍝ How many times does 1, for example, appear in the vector Using the compress function?
+/ (lst = 1)  ⍝ Appears twice
2

⍝ Find the locations of 1 in the vector
(lst = 1) / ⍳ ⍴ lst
2 37          ⍝ Positions 2 and 37
```

So to break down the solution; (i) (lst = 1) generates a boolean vector where true occurs where the int value of 1 exists; (ii) compress the lst vector by the boolean vector creates a new vector with the positions of 'true' in lst.

Correct me if my description is off?

SIMPLIFICATION:

Using the 'Where' function makes it more readable (though the previous method shows how the APL mindset of array programming is used to solve it):

```
⍸lst=1
2 37          ⍝ Positions 2 and 37
```

Thanks for your time on this!

Regards

Comment: just a quick correction - the `/` in `+/` isn't the compress function - it's the reduce operator. For any function `F`, `F/ a b c d e` is equal to `a F b F c F d F e`

Comment: Thanks Probie - much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

While your question has already been amply answered, you may be interested in the Key operator, `⌸`. When its derived function is applied monadically, it takes a single operand and applies it once for each element in the argument. The function is called with the unique element as left argument and the list of its indices as right argument:

```
      lst ← ?100⍴10
      {⍺ ⍵}⌸lst
┌──┬──────────────────────────────────────────┐
│3 │1 3 9 28 37 38 55 70 88                   │
├──┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│10│2 6 13 17 30 59 64 66 71 82 83 96         │
├──┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│7 │4 5 12 15 20 52 54 68 74 85 89 91 92      │
├──┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│9 │7 11 24 47 53 58 69 86 90                 │
├──┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│8 │8 14 16 21 43 51 63 67 73 80              │
├──┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│2 │10 18 26 27 34 36 48 78 79 87             │
├──┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│1 │19 25 31 32 33 42 57 65 75 84 97 98 99 100│
├──┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│6 │22 23 45 46 50 60 76 94                   │
├──┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│5 │29 49 56 61 72 77 93 95                   │
├──┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│4 │35 39 40 41 44 62 81                      │
└──┴──────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBDnFJQqP2iYo2BsaGDzq3WJowAUU4ap@1LtLPbGgIDWxqFghM09d41Hnoke9WzXVC/KLM0sy8/M0ijWt1IEitY96dgA1AAA)

Comment: Thank you Adam for your time on this - very helpful. תודה